# why running `mix phx.server` will enter `dev.exs` for `contex-sample` project?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am trying to use `contex` project for svg server-side rendering learning.

The basic question about `phoenix` project. Why running `mix phx.server` will start `dev.config`, not `prod.config`, how it is triggered?

`dev.config` will start 4000 port, `prod.config` will start 80 port.

[contex-sample project](https://github.com/mindok/contex-samples)

```
Clone this repository with git clone https://github.com/mindok/contex-samples.git
cd contex-samples
Install dependencies with mix deps.get
Install Node.js dependencies with cd assets && npm install
Start Phoenix endpoint with mix phx.server
Now you can visit localhost:4000 from your browser.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mix` puts this `ENV` setting by default (as when you run `mix test`, `:test` environment is activated.) One might change this with [`Mix.Task.preferred_cli_env/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Task.html#preferred_cli_env/1).

In general, `mix` is a development tool, which is not even included in the release. The typical way to start a production server would be to build a release and run it.

If you are still after running `mix phx.server` in `:prod` environment, do `MIX_ENV=prod mix phx.server`.